# Node-Cron not working properly on Digital Ocean

Tags: node.js, cron, momentjs, digital-ocean, node-cron

I am running a cron job every hour but it is not working as expected.
It should run every hour on the hour, for example 1pm, 2pm, 3pm and so on.
But it is running 30 minutes late. 1:30pm, 2:30pm and so on...

I am using `node-cron` in Node.js and server is Digital Ocean Ubuntu.

**Here is the code**

```
var moment = require('moment');
var cron = require('node-cron');
cron.schedule('0 * * * *', function () {
    console.log('cron job started at ' + moment().utcOffset(330).format());
});
```

**Output**
-Its running delay of 30 minutes
cron job started at 2018-02-10T17:30:00+05:30
cron job started at 2018-02-10T18:30:00+05:30
cron job started at 2018-02-10T19:30:00+05:30
cron job started at 2018-02-10T20:30:00+05:30

**I want output as**- at every hour start

cron job started at 2018-02-10T17:00:00+05:30
cron job started at 2018-02-10T18:00:00+05:30
cron job started at 2018-02-10T19:00:00+05:30
cron job started at 2018-02-10T20:00:00+05:30

Comment: `.utcOffset(330)` remove this part to display the time in your servers timezone.

Answer (score 1):

You're changing the timezone of what `moment()` returns by adding 3.5h by calling `.utcOffset(330)`.
Remove the call to `utcOffset()` and it should show the correct time.